# Does Mac really not have keyboard shortcuts to jump to start/end of a document?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

As a software developer, I reckon Ctrl+Home / Ctrl+End are almost as widely used on Windows as copy/paste. These jump the cursor to the start/end of a document respectively.

I've never found a reliable alternative on Mac, and also see inconsistency between different apps... Which means I end up scrolling a *lot* or using PgUp/PgDn.

*Is* there a a standard shortcut when editing a text file or document, to move the cursor to the start/end? If so what is it? Or maybe there's a way to configure it somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### For moving the insertion point to the beginning or end of a document and scrolling it into view:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>.

#### For scrolling to the beginning or end of a document without moving the insertion point:

- Extended Mac keyboards have dedicated <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> buttons.
- All Mac keyboards with a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key provide the <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> key combinations which map, respectively, to *Home* and *End* functions.

###### Note that all of the above behavior is standardized across most Mac apps via system frameworks, but any app is free to override its key-down event handler to behave differently. For example, some apps may choose to move the insertion point when you press <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>. An application may offer the user a preference or setting that controls this behavior.

Comment: Command up/down _seems_ to be what I was after. Home/End are very inconsistent between apps. Though I note even the former doesn't work in every case I tried.

Comment: The inconsistency hurts.  Today I unpleasantly learned that Cmd+Up/Down reorders the slides in Google Slides.  So much for non-destructive navigation.

Comment: @SteveOnorato Yeah, one of a plethora of reasons that I'm not a fan of anything Google produces.

Answer (score 1):

So, exists in Word, checked in the Word help:

[image]

Comment: App-specific shortcuts are a huge PITA. Imagine if copy/paste was different in each app :)

Comment: @Mr.Boy I find keyboard shortcuts to be better standardized across the Mac than the Lenovo thing work gives me...

Answer (score 1):

According to this support document https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201236

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow moves the insertion point to the end of the document, and <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow moves the insertion point to the start of the document.

That works in TextEdit (the exemplar of MacOS TextView APIs).

<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd> often work in other apps, such as BBEdit. (<kbd>Command</kbd> on Mac being analogous to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> on Windows.)